# infinite set of mutually irrational numbers which odd linear combinations approximate 0 badly

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, irrational-numbers

I'm looking for a set of real numbers $\{\lambda_i;i\geq 1\}$ such that for each odd $n$, one can control $\delta_n:=\inf| \sum_i \pm n_i \lambda_i|$ where the $n_i$ are natural integers that sum to $n$.

If I don't want this quantity to be $0$ I need the $\lambda_i$ to be "linearly independent", i.e. there should not be integers $n_1,...,n_p$ such that $\sum_i \pm n_i \lambda_i=0$.

I don't have a preconceived idea on what $\delta_n$ should be, I'm not even sure it is possible to have $\delta_3\neq 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\lambda_1$ be a transcendental number with $1 < \lambda_1$, 
and for $i > 1$ take $\lambda_i = 1 + (i!)^2 \lambda_1^i$.  This implies
that 
$\lambda_{k+1} > 1 + k \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i$.  Thus if
$\left|\sum_i m_i \lambda_i\right| < 1$ where $m_i$ are integers with $\sum_i |m_i| = n$, we must have $m_i = 0$ for $i > n$.
So $\delta_n$ is the infimum of a finite set of nonzero numbers
(nonzero because $\sum_i \pm n_i \lambda_i$ is a non-constant polynomial in the transcendental number $\lambda_1$ with integer coefficients), and therefore is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks, very nice! I really need a control over $\delta_n$, do you have any idea of a lead to estimate it?

Comment: The phrase to look up is "transcendence measure".